# How to pass parameters from jQuery ajax into PHP function?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have this:

PHP:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_count_messages', 'count_messages');
function count_messages($projectid) {
    //some code
    wp_send_json_success($projectid);
}
```

JS:

```
var countData = {
    'action': 'count_messages',
    'projectid': '100'
}
var myRequest =
    $.ajax({
        url: admin_ajax.ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        data: countData
        });
myRequest.done(function(data){ console.log(data); });
```

When I check console, I get:

```
{success: true, data: ""}
```

I am not sure what is happening and why I get an empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you send from jQuey to PHP is in the `$_POST` variable. So you can use `$_POST['projectid']` inside your PHP function to get the data.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a REST API endpoint instead?

e.g. lets register our endpoint:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
        register_rest_route( 'rollor/v1', '/count_messages/', array(
                'methods' => 'GET',
                'callback' => 'count_messages'
        ) );
} );
```

Then the implementation:

```
function count_messages($request) {
    return $request['projectid'];
}
```

Now you can visit `yoursite.com/wp-json/rollor/v1/count_messages?projectid=123`

#### Adding Validation

We can even extend it to add built in validation, and put the project ID in the URL:

```
        register_rest_route( 'rollor/v1', '/count_messages/(?P<projectid>\d+)', array(
                'methods' => 'GET',
                'callback' => 'count_messages',
                'args' => array(
                    'projectid' => function($param,$request,$key) {
                        return is_numeric($param);
                    }
                )
        ) );
```

Now we can visit `yoursite.com/wp-json/rollor/v1/count_messages/123`. It will even tell us if we got it wrong in plain english.

And finally:

```
var myRequest =
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://example.com/wp-json/rollor/v1/count_messages/' + projectid,
});
myRequest.done(function(data){ console.log(data); });
```

Comment: thank you. I am now trying to port all my code into REST, because unlike classic admin-ajax.php, it is actually fun to debug wow

Comment: Is there a quick and clean way to make $current_user, or get_current_user_id(), or a workaround, to work with REST API?

Comment: It should work the same way as any other, but if you're needing to implement user auth, the API can handle that with the appropriate arguments when you register it, you should not need to do any validation or auth checking in the endpoint function itself